# xhr poll error socket io / React-Native / ExpressJs

Tags: react-native, express, socket.io

I'm building an app with you can pay by scanning a QR code with some points.

I'm trying to open web socket with socket io :

In my client (RN app)

```js
import io from "socket.io-client";

//Inside my component vvv
const socket = io(url)
socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
        console.log(err.message)
 });
```

On My server :

```js
const app = express()
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

/**
 * Socket io 
 */
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    console.log('new connection')
})
```

This code log me an error on my client console:

> xhr poll error

I tried every solutions I found on the internet but I'm not able to fix this error.
I also try with `url ="localhost"` & with `url="myIP"` but it does not work.

**Edit :** After 2 days, I resolved my problem !

On my server, I was listening on my app but I had to listen on my server :

I replaced :

```js
app.listen(4000, () => {
        console.log('listening on 4000')
})
```

by

```js
server.listen(4000, () => {
        console.log('listening on 4000')
})
```

where

```js
const server = http.createServer(app);
```

And now it's working well... What a mistake...